# File Permissions Script

Tags: shell-script, permissions, chmod

I'm new to scripting and need assistance writing a script that will go in the /var/log directory, and change all directories's permissions to 777 and all the files permissions to 666 in Linux. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Any particular reason why you wouldn't want to do this? Also, what have you tried already? The script should just consist of the commands you would use yourself.

Comment: Why do you need any directory to be world writable?  That's a security risk. If you absolutely must do this, then it's as simple as creating another directory and creating a script with commands to edit the permissions.

Comment: It's just to practice with the chmod cmd and also gain some familiarity with script writing. Thanks for the contribution

Comment: @Eugene If you "just need to practice", then you should _definitely not_ do that on system directories like `/var/log`.  Set up a small testing directory in you home directory instead.  Changing stuff in `/var/log` implies doing things as the root user. Being the root user is not something you need to be when getting familiar with the basics of how file and folder permissions work.

Answer (score 1):

Making `/var/log/` directory writable could be a security risk.
You shouldn't practice your coding skill with any system directory.

Your question is confused: you didn't tell us that you want to change permission for directories and files **recursively** or not; so I will cover both cases in my answer.

- If you want to change permission **recursively**:

```
sudo find /var/log/ -type d -exec chmod 777 '{}' \;
sudo find /var/log/ -type f -exec chmod 666 '{}' \;
```

- If you want to change permission **non-recursively**:

```
# This does show hidden files
sudo find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec chmod 777 '{}' \;
sudo find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod 666 '{}' \;
```

or

```
# This does NOT show hidden files
sudo find /var/log/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec chmod 777 '{}' \;
sudo find /var/log/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec chmod 666 '{}' \;
```

You can use `man` to learn more about parameters of these utilities.

Comment: Thanks all for the priceless contributions...really appreciate it!